# Sporadic LifetimeScope issues

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, orchardcms, autofac, orchardcms-1.6, lifetime-scoping

Crosspost: https://orchard.codeplex.com/discussions/471475

Sometimes, I get this error:
**"Instances cannot be resolved and nested lifetimes cannot be created from this LifetimeScope as it has already been disposed."** when querying some Content Items.

This is my function that builds the items:

```
        protected IEnumerable<ContentItem> GetResources(string[] productFilters, string[] topicFilters, string[] techLevelFilters)
        {                  
            var cacheKey = BuildCacheKey(productFilters, topicFilters, techLevelFilters);
            var resourceItems = ContentManager.Query().ForType("Resource").ForVersion(VersionOptions.Published).List();

            if (productFilters != null && productFilters.Any())
            {
                resourceItems = resourceItems.Where(r => productFilters.Contains(GetTaxonomyFieldValue(r, productTaxonomy)));
            }

            if (topicFilters != null && topicFilters.Any())
            {
                resourceItems = resourceItems.Where(r => topicFilters.Contains(GetTaxonomyFieldValue(r, topicTaxonomy)));
            }

            if (techLevelFilters != null && techLevelFilters.Any())
            {
                resourceItems = resourceItems.Where(r => techLevelFilters.Contains(GetTaxonomyFieldValue(r, techLevelTaxonomy)));
            }

            return _cacheManager.Get(cacheKey, ctx =>
            {
                ctx.Monitor(_clock.When(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(CacheTime)));
                return resourceItems;
            });
        }
```

This is part of the function that calls the one above, which at times shows the error:

```
            string[] newProductFilters = GetProductFilters(0);
            if (newProductFilters != null && newProductFilters.Any())
            {
                productFilters = productFilters.Concat(newProductFilters).ToArray();
            }     

            var resourceItems = GetResources(productFilters, topicFilters, techLevelFilters);
```

It happens sporadically and I can't really find a cause of the issue. Any piece of advise or information would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: It's totally unclear how you do work with your dependencies. How do you inject them? Do you use a lifetimescope directly? Could you post more code, stack trace of the error please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that your `resourceItems` variable is still a LINQ enumerable which is referenced from the `_cacheManager.Get` lambda. When that lambda actually gets executed, I suspect that the objects it refers to have already been disposed. I would recommend executing the enumerable before referencing it in the lambda. Something like:

```
var finalResourceItems = resourceItems.ToList();

return _cacheManager.Get(cacheKey, ctx =>
{
    ctx.Monitor(_clock.When(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(CacheTime)));
    return finalResourceItems;
});
```

Comment: I think so. But I would write this like this http://pastebin.com/pXidWHs7 . Wrapping the whole method inside the Cache Get.

Comment: @martinbc That would also work, just remember to execute the enumerable in that case as well (`return resourceItems.ToList();) as you would still get the same problems

Comment: It is just the way I code Orchard Cached methods. It works for me.

Comment: brilliant! .ToList() saved my day!